# Correct Path to File

Tags: java, file, path

I don't know why but I cannot seem to get my head wrapped around paths in Java (I'm a Linux admin so that is my reference point). I have the following directory tree:

```
KCBSEvents
    src
        KCBSEvents
            <Java class source files>
        KCBSEvents.Images
            <jpg Image files>
        KCBSEvents.resources
             <resource files>
```

In a class in KCBSEvents>src>KCBSEvents I am trying to read a jpg file from KCBSEvents.Images.

```
File file=new File("../KCBSEvents.Images/KCBSLogo.jpg");
try {
        image=ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting a can't read input file exception. Can someone help me figure out what the correct path should be? I don't understand why the path is wrong. The '..' goes up one level to 'src' and that is where KCBSEvents.Images lives. That jpg file is indeed in that directory. TIA.

Comment: Can you please post the exception.

Comment: post the definition of read method as well. On which line is the exception?

Comment: The reverenced duplicate creates an InputStream object. Doesn't ImageIO.read require a File object?

Comment: Here is the exception:

Comment: Here is the part of the traceback that can fit. Line 56 is the ImageIO.read line:
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at KCBSEvents.SplashScreen.initialize(SplashScreen.java:56)
 at KCBSEvents.SplashScreen.<init>(SplashScreen.java:20)
 at KCBSEvents.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:30)